# jQuery development bundle

Tags: jquery

The jQuery UI library comes in multiple forms: 
1) A one-file minified version
2) A one-file non-minified version
 3) A multiple file non-minified "development bundle"

I'm interested in the equivalent of the "development bundle" for jQuery. Where can I find it?

Comment: Hi, I am new to jQuery, I found "Development bundle" in the zip file, can I delete it? What is the purpose to have it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google CDN hosts a non-minified version of the jQuery library:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js

And github is the home of the:

> multiple file non-minified "development bundle"

https://github.com/jquery/jquery

The files you want are in the "src" directory I believe.

Comment: +1 Good call, I didn't know about this. Gonna bookmark it. :)

Comment: Thanks, but this is actually not what I'm looking for. The files I'm looking for are called jquery.async.js, jquery.autoEllipsis.js, jquery.checkboxShitfClick.js, jquery.client.js, etc.